# How to read word for word that are only separated by a ":" from the buffer?

Tags: c, buffer

I am making a language translator, and want to read from the buffer word by word and store them in a key-value struct.

The buffer contains such a file:

```
hola:hello
que:what
```

and so on. I already tried everything and I keep errors such as segmentation fault: 11 or just reading the same line again and again.

```
struct key_value{
char *key;
char *value;
};
```

...

```
struct key_value *kv = malloc(sizeof(struct key_value) * count);
char k[20]; //key
char v[20]; //value
int x = 0;
for(i = 0; i < numbytes; i++){
    sscanf(buffer,"%21[^:]:%21[^\n]\n",k,v);
    (kv + i)->key = k;
    (kv + i)->value = v;
}

for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    printf("key:  %s, value:  %s\n",(kv + i)->key,(kv + i)->value);
}

free(buffer);
free(kv);
```

I expect the output to be `key: hola, value: hello key: que, value: what`,
but the actual output is just `key: hola, value: hello` again and again.

Which is the right way to do it?

Comment: I suggest to read the whole line with `fgets` and parse it with the help of `strtok` or `strchr`.

Comment: Even if you get this working, it will be a truly abysmal translator. Why not use existing tools like Google's translation API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a simple piece of code that may help you to solve your problem. I've used the function `fgets` to read from a file named "file.txt" and the function `strchr` to individuate the 1st occurence of the separator `':'`.

Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE       256
#define MAX_DECODED_LINE    1024

struct decod {
    char key[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char value[MAX_DECODED_LINE];
};

static struct decod decod[1024];

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fptr = NULL;

    char fbuf[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char * value;
    int cnt=0,i;

    if ( !(fptr=fopen("file.txt","r")) )
    {
        perror("");
        return errno;
    }

    while( fgets(fbuf,MAX_LINE_SIZE,fptr)) {
        // Eliminate UNIX/DOS line terminator
        value=strrchr(fbuf,'\n');
        if (value) *value=0;
        value=strrchr(fbuf,'\r');
        if (value) *value=0;

        //Find first occurrence of the separator ':'
        value=strchr(fbuf,':');
        if (value) {
            // Truncates fbuf string to first word
            // and (++) points second word
            *value++=0;
        }

        if (cnt<MAX_DECODED_LINE) {
            strcpy(decod[cnt].key,fbuf);
            if (value!=NULL) {
                strcpy(decod[cnt].value,value);
            } else {
                decod[cnt].value[0]=0;
            }
            cnt++;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,
                 "Cannot read more than %d lines\n", MAX_DECODED_LINE);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fptr)
        fclose(fptr);

    for(i=0;i<cnt;i++) {
        printf("key:%s\tvalue:%s\n",decod[i].key,decod[i].value);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code reads all the lines (max 1024) that the file named file.txt contains, loads all individuated couples (max 1024) into the `struct array` `decod` and then printouts the content of the structure.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code, among them

- On each loop iteration, you read from the *beginning* of the buffer.  It is natural, then, that each iteration extracts the same key and value.
- More generally, your read loop iteration variable seems to have no relationship with the data read.  It appears to be a per-byte iteration, but you seem to want a per-*line* iteration.  You might want to look into `scanf`'s `%n` directive to help you track progress through the buffer.
- You are scanning each key / value pair into the same local `k` and `v` variables, then you are assigning pointers to those variables to your structures.  The resulting pointers are all the same, *and* they will become invalid when the function returns.  I suggest giving `struct`key_value` arrays for its members instead of pointers, and copying the data into them.
- Your `sscanf` format reads up to 21 characters each for key and value, but the provided destination arrays are not long enough for that.  You need them to be dimensioned for at least 22 characters to hold 21 plus a string terminator.
- Your `sscanf()` format and usage do not support recognition of malformed input, especially overlength keys or values.  You need to check the return value, and you probably need to match the trailing newline with a `%c` field (the literal newline in the format does not mean what you think it means).

Tokenizing (the whole buffer) with `strtok_r` or `strtok` or even `strchr` instead of `sscanf()` might be easier for you.

Also, style note: your expressions of the form `(kv + i)->key` are valid, but it would be more idiomatic to write `kv[i].key`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code, I think it does the job! this is simpler than the accepted answer I think! and it uses just as much as memory is needed, no more.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct key_value{
    char key[22];
    char value[22];
};

void parse_str(char* str, struct key_value** kv_arr, int* num){

    int  n    = 0;
    int  read = -1;
    char k[22];
    char v[22];
    int current_pos = 0;
    int consumed    = 0;

    /*counting number of key-value pairs*/
    while (1){
        if(current_pos > strlen(str)){
            break;
        }
        read = sscanf(str + current_pos, "%21[^:]:%21[^\n]\n%n", k, v, &consumed);
        current_pos += consumed;

        if(read == 2){
            ++n;
        }
    }
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    *kv_arr = malloc(sizeof(struct key_value) * n);



    /*filling key_value array*/
    int i       = 0;
    read        = -1;
    current_pos = 0;
    consumed    = 0;
    while (1){
        if(current_pos > strlen(str)){
            break;
        }
        read = sscanf(str + current_pos, "%21[^:]:%21[^\n]\n%n", k, v, &consumed);
        current_pos += consumed;

        if(read == 2){
            struct key_value* kv = &((*kv_arr)[i]);
            strncpy(kv->key, k, 22);
            strncpy(kv->value, v, 22);
            ++i;
        }
    }

    *num = n;
}


int main(){

    char* str = "hola:hello\n"
                "que:what\n";

    int n;
    struct key_value* kv_arr;

    parse_str(str, &kv_arr, &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s  <--->  %s\n", kv_arr[i].key, kv_arr[i].value);
    }


    free(kv_arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**output :**

```
n = 2
hola  <--->  hello
que  <--->  what
```

Process finished with exit code 0

---

**Note**: `sscanf` operates on a `const char*`, not an input stream from a file, so it will **NOT** store any information about what it has consumed.

**solution** :  I used `%n` in the format string to get the number of characters that it has consumed so far (C89 standard).

Comment: It's terribly nice of you to write a complete program for someone, but it may be difficult for them to compare their program to yours to see what the problem was. Brevity is the soul of both wit and good answers.